# manipulation of classes in java

Tags: java

I'm getting confused about how to extract data from a custom class. The code groups Cartesian coordinates in a class called `linesegment`, with several instances of class `CartesianCoordinate` as its members.  I am stuck trying to find the distance between two sets of cartesian coordinates.

How am I supposed to decode the `linesegment` class, into the `cartesiancoordinate` class, to then access the individual `double` values to print to screen from the main class?

Below are the three classes used within my program:

The main class:

```java
public class lab3
{

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        cartesiancoordinate one, two; //instantsiating one and two as type cartesiancoordiante
        one = new cartesiancoordinate(5, 6); //putting the information for one and two into type cartesiancoordinate
        two = new cartesiancoordinate(4.5, -6.5); 

        linesegment oneandtwo;
        oneandtwo = new linesegment(one, two);      

        System.out.println(one.toString()); //dual X/Y statements using a toString method
        System.out.println(two.toString());     

        System.out.println(oneandtwo.tostring());

        System.out.println("X for one is: " + one.getx()); //individual X/Y statements using getter methods
        System.out.println("Y for one is: " + one.gety());
        System.out.println("X for two is: " + two.getx()); //individual X/Y statements using getter methods
        System.out.println("Y for two is: " + two.gety());

        double tester;
        oneandtwo.test();       
        System.out.println("The test method returned the distance between the two cartesian coordinates to be: " + tester);
    }
}
```

The cartesiancoordinate class:

```java
class cartesiancoordinate 
{
    private double xposition;
    private double yposition;

    public cartesiancoordinate(double x, double y)
    {
        this.xposition = x;
        this.yposition = y;
    }

    public double getx()
    {
        return this.xposition;
    }

    public double gety()
    {
        return this.yposition;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return "(" + this.xposition + " / " + this.yposition + ")";
    }
}
```

The troublesome linesegment class:

```java
class linesegment
{
    private cartesiancoordinate startpoint, endpoint, s1, e1;    
    public cartesiancoordinate one, two;


    public linesegment(cartesiancoordinate x, cartesiancoordinate y)
    {
        this.startpoint = x;
        this.endpoint = y;
    }

    public cartesiancoordinate getstartpoint()
    {
        return this.startpoint;
    }

    public cartesiancoordinate getendpoint()
    {
        return  this.endpoint;
    }

    public String tostring()
    {
        return ("The start point is " + this.startpoint + " and the end point is " + this.endpoint);
    }


    public double test()
    {

        double x1,x2,y1,y2;
        cartesiancoordinate s1,e1;

        getstartpoint() = s1;
        getendpoint() = e1 ;

        s1.getx() = x1;
        s1.gety() = y1;
        e1.getx() = x2;
        e1.gety() = y2;

        double tester;
        tester = x1 + x2 + y1 + y2;
        return tester;
    }
}
```

Comment: Side note on code quality: read about java coding style guidelines; your names for methods and classes are simply ... completely "wrong". Beyond that, your naming is also "bad" (in the not helpful sense): a method should say what it is doing. So, what is **test** testing? And why is it returning a double? Finally: consider turning to JUnit unit tests; instead of manual "tests" from static main methods.

Comment: Nothing in particular distinguishes classes you write ("custom classes") from those provided in the standard library with respect to how you can manipulate them and extract data from them.  Your `cartesiancoordinate` class provides methods for extracting the individual coordinates -- use them.  Your `linesegment` class provides methods for getting the `cartesiancoordinate` objects representing the starting and ending points -- use them.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, I have just read up on as to why camel case is important in coding - I am new to this style and can see the benefits of this. And as for when you say "use them" - this was exactly the problem I was trying to address, and it is now solved. thank you again for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
double tester;
oneandtwo.test();
```

You want:

```
double tester = oneandtwo.test();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I have now got the code up and running!

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem.

```
getstartpoint() = s1;
getendpoint() = e1 ;
```

Your methods are `return`-ing values, so if you want to assign them to `s1` and `e1`, then you can do that like so

```
s1 = getstartpoint();
e1 = getendpoint();
```

That won't fix the logic of your code, but it should at least compile.

Answer (score 0):

Your `linesegment` class is broken:

```
class linesegment {
    // a linesegment is nothing more than defined by a starting and ending point
    private cartesiancoordinate startpoint, endpoint;    

    public linesegment(cartesiancoordinate x, cartesiancoordinate y) {
        this.startpoint = x;
        this.endpoint = y;
    }

    public cartesiancoordinate getstartpoint() {
        return this.startpoint;
    }

    public cartesiancoordinate getendpoint() {
        return  this.endpoint;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return ("The start point is " + this.startpoint + " and the end point is " + this.endpoint);
    }    

    public double test()
    {
        double dx = endpoint.getx()-startpoint.getx();
        double dy = endpoint.gety()-startpoint.gety();
        return Math.sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy);
    }
}
```

Now in the main:

```
double tester = oneandtwo.test(); // get the distance
System.out.println("Distance is "+tester);
```

Please use standard naming conventions. Your classes must be spelled `CartesianCoordinates`, `LineSegment`, `Lab3`. Your variables: `oneAndTwo`, `startPoint`, `endPoint`...

Comment: Thank you for your help - It is greatly appreciated and now I can move forward! I have just changed all the names of the classes/variables to a camel case style, once again thanks.